# Cant get good distortion

Tags: distortion

I have a ZAR E20R amp and I pump my gain to max but still feel like i get no distortion at all, is there something I can do in EQ to boost it or am I just doomed and need to get a pedal?[image]

Comment: Did you push in the "On" button on the Overdrive channel?

Comment: Yeh, I pushed the on button haha. I also know some amps require higher volume for better distortion, tried that too, but changed nothing.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the actual settings that aren’t working? Have you tried putting treble, bass, and middle on 10?

Comment: @paskoo did this amp come with a foot switch? Some amps could only switch channels with the foot switch. It's a stretch but figured I would ask anyway.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89932/new-to-electric-guitar-need-help-with-amp-settings Why not add additional information to that rather than post an almost identical question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New to electric guitar, need help with amp settings](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89932/new-to-electric-guitar-need-help-with-amp-settings)

Comment: I don't get good distortion with any settings at all, and no, the amp didn't come with a foot switch.